# DJNZ command in Universal Register Machine

Tags: turing-machines, computability, coding-theory, counting, shift-register

How do I represent DJNZ command of counting machine via commands of Universal Register Machine, those commands are CLR JNE INC and TR, via this commands i have to represent DJNZ command, any help would be great.

Comment: Can you share the context?  What is the source you are using for the definition of a universal register machine?  What are the semantics of the DJNZ command?

Comment: DJNZ command  applied to (n,q) does following if Rn !=0 then decrases Rn for 1, furthermore again it checks if Rn!=0 if not again it decreases Rn for 1... and puts pointer(counter) to q-th spot in code.

Comment: About context of URM CLR(n) puts Rn to 0 INC(n) increases Rn for 1 TR(n,m) transfers Rn to Rm and JNE (jump if not equal) (n,m,q) it checks if Rn!=Rm if it is different that puts pointer on q-th spot in code

Comment: Please don't put clarifications into the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so it is self-contained, has all the information needed to answer the question, and reads well for someone who encounters this page for the first time.  Thank you!